# Que es skip-grant-tables en mysql y porqué puede suponer un peligro de seguridad para las bases de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo un amigo que me comentó lo siguiente; él tenía una página web en desarrollo con phpmyadmin funcionando perfectamente, pero me explicó que después de unas largas actualizaciones de su computadora se le arrojó el error de `Acceso denegado` y algo sobre parámetros inválidos  para acceder a `phpmyadmin`. Busqué en unos cuantos vídeos sobre como solucionar el problema, y a pesar que en los vídeos de youtube así mismo en las páginas informativas decían que era un problema común, no había mucho movimiento y todo eran respuestas diferentes y indecisas.
Pero llegó `skip-grant-tables` que decían que si se ponía en el archivo `my.ini` debajo de `mysqld` el problema desapareció y las bases de datos volvieron a trabajar, pero me pregunto;

Que es `skip-grant-tables` y que hace en concreto para que funcione otra vez el `mysql`?
Y supone poner eso un riesgo para la base de datos, ya que por investigación que hecho se dice que eso es peligroso ya que deja acceso a cualquiera para acceder a la base de datos sin restricción de base de datos.
Solo quiero aclarar dudas, gracias.

Mi amigo me ha comentado que ha visto un cambio en su página web, después de poner `skip-grant-tables` dice que la página se ve más pequeña, como que haya afectado al `css`. Es eso posible?

Para trabajar sin tener riesgos de seguridad estamos trabajando en el localhost surgiendo estos errores los mismos que se pueden ver al intentar ingresar a la interfaz local de `phpmyadmin`:
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

*----  No se estableció la conexión: los parámetros están incorrectos.*

*------ mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server*

*-----   La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.*

*------   mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server*

*-----    phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que corresponden con la información provista por el administrador del servidor MySQL.*

Aquí pide revisar el `conif.inc.php` y entiendo, ha habido una fuga de privilegios pero es muy extraño, ya que esto no tendría que pasar,  estamos sospechando (solo es una sospecha) que puede que el puerto haya cambiado durante esas actualizaciones, y puede que esa sea una fuente del error, pero dicho, solo son sospechas.

Comment: Pues, no le veo mucho sentido que un cambio a nivel de base de datos tenga efectos en el css de un sitio web. ¿Seguro que no hay detalles intermedios que están faltando?

Answer (score 2):

Tu pregunta me pareció muy interesante, a pesar de no ser un problema específico de programación, ya que es posible que alguna vez mi [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) deje de funcionar. De modo que decidí documentarme un poco al respecto.

En la documentación oficial de **Oracle - MySql [Server Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html)** se encuentran algunas referencias importantes (sólo traduciré el elemento nuclear):

1. Cuando se inicia el servidor habiendo habilitado **skip-grant-tables** los plugins registrados en la tabla de plugins del sistema para arranque normal **no son cargados**.

> During the normal startup sequence, the server determines which plugins to load by reading the mysql.plugins system table. If the server is started with the --skip-grant-tables option, plugins registered in the mysql.plugins table are not loaded and are unavailable.

2. Inmediatamente después se indica una solución: **cargarlos usando la directiva:** `--plugin-load`:

> --plugin-load enables plugins to be loaded even when --skip-grant-tables is given. --plugin-load also enables plugins to be loaded at startup that cannot be loaded at runtime.

3. Como consecuencia directa se anula el control de privilegios de acceso y cualquiera que tenga acceso al servidor puede **ingresar con privilegios absolutos a todas las bases de datos**. (El sistema de tu amigo quedó en cucos - algunas veces puede ser peor el remedio que la enfermedad)

> --skip-grant-tables causes the server not to read the grant tables in the mysql system schema, and thus to start without using the privilege system at all. **This gives anyone with access to the server *unrestricted access to all databases***.

4. Dentro de la formulación de la pregunta indicas que hubo largas actualizaciones del sistema y pérdida de privilegios de acceso:

> "... pero me explicó que después de unas largas actualizaciones de su computadora se le arrojó el error de **Acceso denegado** y algo sobre parámetros inválidos para acceder a [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin) ..."

Eso coincide con la casuística señalada en la documentación de referencia pues puede haberse presentado una eliminación de privilegios por efecto de dichas actualizaciones:

> Privilege flushing might also occur implicitly as a result of other actions performed after startup, thus causing the server to start using the grant tables. For example, **the server flushes the privileges if it performs an upgrade during the startup sequence**.

5. Dentro del enunciado anterior "*thus causing the server to start using the grant tables*" me confunde a la hora de presentar la alternativa de solución, porque en la misma documentación se indica usar la sentencia (statement) `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` para reiniciar el control de privilegios recargando las tablas de concesión de los mismos **en tiempo de ejecución**:

> En [FLUSH statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-privileges) (...) Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql system schema. As part of this operation, the server reads the global_grants table containing dynamic privilege assignments and registers any unregistered privileges found there.
>
> If the --skip-grant-tables option was specified at server startup to disable the MySQL privilege system, FLUSH PRIVILEGES provides a way to enable the privilege system at runtime.
>
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES resets failed-login tracking (or enables it if the server was started with --skip-grant-tables) and unlocks any temporarily locked accounts. See Section 6.2.15, “Password Management”.

De las anotaciones anteriores se infiere que:

- Se debe ejecutar `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` en la próxima recarga del sitio, o desde la consola de comandos. Y, una vez restaurados
- Volver a su estado por defecto **off** la directiva `skip-grant-tables` y reiniciar.

**Como nunca me he visto en la misma situación, ni la he probado *No me consta, ni tengo certeza* de que pueda funcionar**. Simplemente presento un resumen de la consulta realizada a propósito de la pregunta y lo que de la misma se puede inferir.

En cuanto al asunto de la afectación de los estilos, no creo que haya correlación directa (a no ser que los mismos sean guardados en las BB.DD., que no creo que sea el caso)

Comment: Increíble respuesta! Entonces se puede afirmar que skip-grant-tables es una mala práctica,  yo y mi amigo vamos a intentar ejecutar FLUSH PRIVILEGES y poner la directiva skip-grant-tables off y reiniciar. Pero quevedo es el FLUSH PRIVILEGES deber ejecutar en la consola de XAMPP? Voy a ir a probar.

Comment: Hola @JackMore, No me atrevería a llamarlo **mala práctica**. Pero, si lo consideraría como un **recurso de sólo una vez** para situaciones excepcionales en las que resulte necesario arrancar sin plugins y forzar la recarga del sistema de privilegios mediante `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` y acto seguido desactivarlo. Usado así, la probabilidad de exposición sería muy baja y puede acompañarse de medidas complementarias.

Comment: Creo que puedes ejecutarlo desde el código, poniendo el **statement** dentro de un query de mantenimiento en una página que se invoque específicamente para ese fin. Pero, no tengo certeza. Al menos por lo que muestra la documentación [FLUSH statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html) debe poder hacerse.

Comment: Vale, claro eso entonces tendría que ir en un archivo que se quiera o no tiene que ir relacionado (relacionado como que tenga influencia) con todos los call a la base, voy a ir investigando y te cuento...

Comment: Estaré al tanto. Pues de momento no tengo un entorno en el que pueda "destrozar" el control de privilegios para simular una prueba coherente.

Comment: Ah. Por favor pregunta a tu amigo si en los mensajes que recibió cuando se produjo el bloqueo hubo alguna referencia a **httpd.pid**

Comment: Ya hice una actualización en la pregunta, borramos skip-grant-tables y copiamos los errores, aclaro que los problemas vienen de una página web en desarollo en  localhost, puede que en una página en la nube pueda arrojar menos, mismos o más problemas.