# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, sql

En el curso de sql que estoy haciendo, el instructor inicia [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) y entra por cli (en windows) `c:\xampp\mysql\bin` y ejecuta el comando 'mysql' y me sale como a el, pero todo se jode cuando hay que agregar al path de windows el permiso para entrar desde cualquier sitio, porque aunque lo hago, pero me arroja:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Y para solucionarlo uso el comando `skip-grant-tables`, pero el post de [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387479/que-es-skip-grant-tables-en-mysql-y-porqu%C3%A9-puede-suponer-un-peligro-de-seguridad?newreg=b86e6143b34f489596e1710571052d46) dice lo peligroso que es.

¿Por qué al instructor no le da problemas y a mí sí?, el tampoco usa contraseña y usa windows 10, ¿entonces por qué ocurre esto?

¿Qué hago en lugar de usar `skip-grant-tables`?

Gracias.